# Applying a criterion to a single column of a table in pander

Tags: subset, r-markdown, pander

I want to apply a criterion according to which cells in a pander table are made bold or not. However I want to apply this criterion to a single column of the table not to other columns.

Here is the full markdown document.

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```


```{r toy data}

pVal <- as.character(c(0.9, 0.04, 0.6, 0.0003))
FVal <- as.character(c(0.03, 2.51, 1.7, 32.1))
Group <- c("A", "B", "C", "D")
df <- data.frame(Group, FVal, pVal, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

library(pander)

emphasize.strong.cells(which(df < 0.05, arr.ind = TRUE))

pander(df)
```
````

There are two problems here.

First is the fact that the values that fulfill the criterion in the `FVal` column are also made bold. I want the values <.05 made bold in the `pVal` column *only*. I tried subsetting in the `emphasize.strong.cells` function like so

```
emphasize.strong.cells(which(df$pVal < 0.05, arr.ind = TRUE))
```

or

```
emphasize.strong.cells(which(df[,"pVal"] < 0.05, arr.ind = TRUE))
```

But neither worked. I suspect this is happening because subsetting this way I am not giving the `emphasize.strong.cells` function an object with several dimensions but I am not sure how to make an object like that where only one column is 'active' for the criterion.

The second issue is that the final element in the `pVal` column is not made bold in the final rmarkdown pdf, i assume because of the transformation to scientific notation.

Any solutions much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is rather a `matrix` manipulation question rather than specific to `pander`, as `emphasize.cells` takes a `matrix` returned by `which(..., arr.ind = TRUE)` that is to be filtered for the 3rd column if my understand on this question is right. See eg:

```
> emphasize.strong.cells(as.matrix(subset(data.frame(which(df < 0.05, arr.ind = TRUE)), col == 3)))
> pander(df)

-----------------------
 Group   FVal    pVal  
------- ------ --------
   A     0.03    0.9   

   B     2.51  **0.04**

   C     1.7     0.6   

   D     32.1   3e-04  
-----------------------
```

Comment: Yes, I always knew it was my lack of understanding of how to isolate that last column. The `subset(., col ==3)` was exactly what I needed. As always you have been very helpful @daroczig.

Answer (score 1):

This simple hack will take care of it for you.

```
df$pVal <- ifelse(df$pVal < 0.05, paste0("**", df$pVal, "**"), df$pVal)
pander(df)


-----------------------
 Group   FVal    pVal  
------- ------ --------
   A     0.03    0.9   

   B     2.51  **0.04**

   C     1.7     0.6   

   D     32.1   3e-04  
-----------------------
```

If you change the `pVal` to `as.numeric`, the final value will also be made bold.

Comment: Thank you at @Maiasaura. A very nice workaround. I'll wait around to see if someone can give me a way of doing the same with the 'in-house' pander function but it got me around the problem in my rmarkdown doc so definitely worth an upvote.